# Intersection of cosets of additive subgroups of GF$^+(2^s)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, finite-fields, change-of-basis

Consider a basis $\left\{ {{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_s}} \right\}$ to GF($2^s$) (for some $s \ge 2$) over GF($2$). I am trying to show the existence of an element $g \in$ GF($2^s$) such that each of the $s-1$ sets 
$$\left\{ {g{w_1},{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 1}}} \right\},\left\{ {g{w_1},g{w_2},{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 2}}} \right\},...,\left\{ {g{w_1},g{w_2},...g{w_{s - 1}},{w_1}} \right\}$$ is a basis to GF($2^s$) over GF($2$).

The observation I made so far is that by discarding $g$ values that **violate** the independence of the sets above, we actually discard additive subgroups of the field. To see this, denote by $\left\langle {{\alpha _1},{\alpha _2},...,{\alpha _s}} \right\rangle $ the span (set of linear combinations) of the field elements ${{\alpha _1},{\alpha _2},...,{\alpha _s}}$ with coefficients taken from GF($2$): $$\left\langle {{\alpha _1},{\alpha _2},...,{\alpha _s}} \right\rangle  = \left\{ {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^s {{\beta _i} \cdot {\alpha _i}:{\beta _i} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}} } \right\}.$$

To ensure linear independence for $\{ {g{w_1},{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 1}}}\}$, $g$ must not belong to the **subgroup** $${\mathcal{S}_1} = \left\langle {{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 1}}} \right\rangle /{w_1} = \left\{ {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{s - 1} {{\beta _i} \cdot {w_i}} :{\beta _i} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}} \right\}/{w_1}.$$
(division is element-wise).

That is, $g$ belongs to a **coset** of $\mathcal{S}_1$. In a similar fashion, to ensure linear independence of the set $\{ {g{w_1},g{w_2},{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 2}}}\}$, $g$ must belong as well to cosets of the subgroups $\mathcal{S}_2 = {\left\langle {{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 2}}} \right\rangle /{w_2}}$ and $\mathcal{S}_3 = \left\langle {{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 2}}} \right\rangle /\left( {{w_1} + {w_2}} \right)$ and so on. In general, set $i$ ($i=1,2,...,s-1$) induces the constraint that $g$ belongs to $2^{i-1}$ cosets of $2^{s-i}$ elements each.

I am trying to show that the intersection of these cosets (note that a coset leader needs to be specified for each coset) is non-empty.

Empirically, I found that using a polynomial basis (regardless of the primitive polynomial in use) and up to $s=12$, there are exactly $2$ such $g$ values for each $s$, where one is the multiplicative inverse of the other. That is, the intersection of the cosets above is of cardinality $2$.

**Example ($s=3$)**

For $s=3$ we need to find $g$ such that the elements in both sets $\left\{ {g{w_1},{w_1},{w_2}} \right\}$ and $\left\{ {g{w_1},g{w_2},{w_1}} \right\}$ are linearly independent. That is, $g$ must belong to the intersection of certain cosets of the subgroups $\left\langle {{w_1},{w_2}} \right\rangle /{w_1} = \left\{ {0,{w_1}/{w_1},\left( {{w_1} + {w_2}} \right)/{w_1},{w_2}/{w_1}} \right\}$, $\left\langle {{w_1}} \right\rangle /{w_2} = \left\{ {0,{w_1}/{w_2}} \right\}$ and $\left\langle {{w_1}} \right\rangle /\left( {{w_1} + {w_2}} \right) = \left\{ {0,{w_1}/\left( {{w_1} + {w_2}} \right)} \right\}$.

Comment: What kind of "set" do you mean by $\;\cfrac{\langle w_1,w_2,...,w_{s-1}\rangle}{w_1}\;$ ? I don't understand the notation.

Comment: @DonAntonio The elements in ${\left\langle {{w_1},{w_2},...,{w_{s - 1}}} \right\rangle }$, each divided by $w_1$. Now added explicitly.